# Crash in Python native extension module: Can interpreter fail gracefully?

Tags: python, error-handling, ipython, cython

I develop an interactive data analysis tool in which C++ high-performance kernels are wrapped via Cython and exposed as Python objects. This works very well in conjunction with IPython. However, a crash in the native code of the extension module (e.g. segmentation fault) will also crash the interpreter so that the entire session is lost. Is it possible to avoid this in any way? Could an error like a segmentation fault be caught as a proper Python exception?

Comment: How would you catch a segfault if you were writing an application in C?  If you know what to do to actually *catch* the exception in native code, reraising it as a python exception is simple.

Comment: @IfLoop Is there a general way to handle unexpected crashes so that they do not crash the interpreter? If I understand you correctly, what you are saying is "Just don't let the extension module crash", but crashes will happen. I'm looking for a way to minimize the damage.

Comment: Even in the specific case of a Segfault, the problem is that your process has performed an illegal operation.  It's not possible for a regular python program to dereference a dangling pointer, those don't exist in the python interpreter, so you can't crash your program in that way, but from C, you certainly can.  Unfortunately, there's no process isolation that's available inside the same process that would protect the python interpreter and let you recover.

Comment: Maybe this topic would help... http://stackoverflow.com/q/17435656/1715716

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [faulthandler module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/faulthandler.html) (new in 3.3, but [available](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/faulthandler) for older versions) can print tracebacks on system-level errors.

Trying to handle the errors from Python code [apparently doesn't work](http://bugs.python.org/issue1215). At the C level, you can install a signal handler for SIGSEGV, but from the information I can find, what you can do there is quite limited. The basic message seems to be that you can shut down gracefully, but you can't recover from a segfault.

Comment: This will not save the session, but print debug info which might be useful. I've added `faulthandler.enable()` to my module.

Answer (score 0):

Let me add that many crashes can be avoided by having C++ standard exceptions be re-raised by Cython. This is done by appending `except +` to the Cython class definition. Example:

```
cdef extern from "../src/Example.h":
    cdef cppclass Example:
        void method() except +
```