# Handle lock overfreeing without SIGILL

Tags: python, python-3.x, pthreads, cython

I'm working on a Python/Cython project that includes a instance of [`pthread` `rwlock`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/pthread_rwlock_init.html), and I'm trying to handle the error cases.

My issue right now is that it appears that there are a bunch of contexts where the lock can throw `SIGILL` and I want to return a better python error/not crash.

I have to say, I've not done much with unix signals, and I'm not sure why it does this in the first place. All the calls that throw SIGILL also have return codes, and it would make much more sense to me for the lock to simply return an error code. Right now, my entire application aborts hard.

Is there a C `rwlock` implementation that doesn't explode when you don't call it exactly the way it wants? Alternatively, is catching and handling something as serious as `SIGILL` normal? Does doing so have other side effects?

---

In response to the comments, here is a minimal example:

```
// For RWLocks
#include <pthread.h>
#include <stdio.h>


int main()
{
    int ret;
    pthread_rwlock_t lock_rw = PTHREAD_RWLOCK_INITIALIZER;

    ret = pthread_rwlock_rdlock(&lock_rw);
    printf("pthread_rwlock_rdlock: %i\n", ret);
    ret = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock_rw);
    printf("pthread_rwlock_unlock: %i\n", ret);
    ret = pthread_rwlock_unlock(&lock_rw);
    printf("pthread_rwlock_unlock: %i\n", ret);

    return 0;
}
```

This creates a normal lock, acquires a read lock, frees the read lock, and then frees the read lock again (overfreeing it).

Console output:

```
$ rm a.out; gcc wat.c -lpthread; ./a.out
pthread_rwlock_rdlock: 0
pthread_rwlock_unlock: 0
Illegal instruction
```

Comment: I know very little about pthreads, but I doubt it's deliberately using `SIGILL` instead of error codes. My guesses are: 1) You're using it very wrongly (and it's built around the assumption you're not using it that way, so not doing any error checking) - if this is the case you built some guards around this misuse yourself; or 2) you have an implementation that's compiled for a processor you don't have (hence illegal instructions)

Comment: If you decide the above two options really aren't the case you might look at handling the signals (see this answer for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17435656/cython-segmentation-fault-handling/17441362#17441362). But I doubt if trying to handle the signals is the right solution.

Comment: @DavidW - If you free a rwlock twice, it throws SIGILL. Yeah, it surprised me too.

Comment: @DavidW - See the new example. What other error checking could I do?

Comment: Associate a boolean with the rwlock to tell you if it's already been freed. Don't call the unlock function if true. Possibly encapsulate the lock and the boolean in some kind of structure and hwork with that structure (and the associated functions) rather than the dangerous raw pthread functions.